# Project settings - Input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've added a new input to *"Project settings - Input"*.

> Restart, key <kbd>R</kbd>

How do I know which key is assigned at the *"Restart"*? I want to make the inscription *"Press <kbd>R</kbd> to restart"*.

Comment: Refer to [Ask], questions posted here should provide a [MCVE], and please complete the 2-minute [tour] before posting again.

Answer (score 0):

The Feature you are asking for, are currently not available in UnityEngine.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets all the input axis defined in the project's Input manager
 /// (gets it from ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset)
 /// </summary>
 public static List<string> GetInputAxis()
 {
     var allAxis = new List<string>();
     var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset")[0]);
     var axesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_Axes");
     axesProperty.Next(true);
     axesProperty.Next(true);
     while (axesProperty.Next(false))
     {
         SerializedProperty axis = axesProperty.Copy();
         axis.Next(true);
         allAxis.Add(axis.stringValue);
     }
     return allAxis;
 }
```

This is a method you can use in the game window, of the editor. Which as stated above, means that you cannot use it when the game is built.

Reference: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/21083/how-do-you-get-the-button-names-assigned-to-an-axi.html